# DynamicReferenceParameter defined in Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I use the DynamicReferenceParameter for some advanced parameter inputs in Jenkins.
Here is a tiny example, which I entered using the UI:
[image]

This works fine, my checkboxes and input fields do show up!

But when I try to define my parameters in my Jenkinsfile, I get an error. My Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
properties([parameters([
    [
        $class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter',
        name: 'SFM',
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript', 
            fallbackScript: '', 
            script: """
                def services = ['service1',
                        'service2',
                        'service3']

                def html =
                '''
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <body>

                <table id="serviceTable">
                '''

                for (service in services){
                    html += "<tr>"
                    html += "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox_$service\">$service</td>"
                    html += "<td><div id=\"version_$service\" >version: <input type=\"text\"></div></td>"
                    html += "</tr>"
                }

                html += '''
                </table>
                </body>
                </html>
                '''
                return html
            """
        ]
    ]
])])
```

You see, I just copy&pasted the script from the UI input and surrounded it with `"""`.

This results in error no. 1:

```
Groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: service for class: WorkflowScript
```

So there is an error parsing my variables.

So I just tried to delete all variables and set static values (replace `$service` with `service1`). This results in error no. 2:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.biouno.unochoice.model.GroovyScript.script expects class org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript but received class java.lang.String
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:416)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:340)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:281)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {fallbackScript=, script=[...]
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`script` and `fallbackScript` are not really String's. They are using the Security Script Plugin classes (it's been like that for a while already).

Here's some code snippet that may help.

```
properties([parameters([
    [
        $class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter',
        name: 'TEST',
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript', 
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [], sandbox: true, script: ''
            ],
            script: [   
                classpath: [], sandbox: true, script: 
                """
                def html =
                '''
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <body>

                <table id="serviceTable">
                    <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">service1</td>
                    <td><div id="version" >version: <input type="text"></div></td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
                </body>
                </html>
                '''
                return html
            """
            ]
        ]
    ]
])])
```

ps: take it with a grain of salt, as I normally use only FreeStyle jobs. I think some people tried using the plug-in with pipelines, but as far as I know, it's still a work-in-progress (see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39742 for example)

Hope that helps,
Bruno

Comment: Thank you! It works, but there was one line missing: `choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML'`

Comment: Guys, how can I access value that someone entered into <input type="text"> ?

Comment: @DaniChe if the input element was created by a dynamic parameter, with formatted html, then it won't be possible. But if this value comes from another active choices parameter, or a vanilla jenkins parameter, just add an active choices using the other parameter as reference, and you should have a variable in groovy bindings with that parameter's name.

Comment: how would you set a multiline value for this that is define out side the script section? in particular im struggling with with building a textarea html and defaulting it's value to a  multi-line text

Answer (score 0):

```
properties([parameters([
    [$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter',
        choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML',
        omitValueField: true,
        description: 'Editable field when PARENT_PARAM is Others',
        name: 'ACTIVE_PARAM',
        randomName: 'choice-parameter-5631314456178624',
        referencedParameters: 'PARENT_PARAM',
        script: [
            $class: 'GroovyScript',
            fallbackScript: [
                classpath: [],
                sandbox: true,
                script: "return['undefined']"
            ],
            script: [
                classpath: [],
                sandbox: true,
                script:
                    """
                    inputBox="<input class='setting-input' name='value' type='text' value=''>"
                    """
            ]
        ]
    ]
])])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).